# Java regex to remove newline and space at the end of string

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to java regex so this question might be easy for someone.
I have a raw string:

```
"\n\n This is \n\r simple \n     string \r   "
```

Now I want to format it to:

```
"This is \n\r simple \n    string"
```

I want to trim this tring at the start and end of this string. But the trim() method works only with the white space (\s).

I try to use replace first

```
replaceFirst("[\\t\\n\\r]", "")
```

and it works fine with the start of the string. But dont see the replace last, so I use

```
replaceAll("[\\t\\n\\r]$", "\n")
```

The "$" will affect only the last one, but in case of "\r\r\n\n", only the last \n replaced.

How can I remove all the "\r\r\n\n" at the last of the string?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Sorry, Im lazy not to test carefully. trim() works fine in this case.

Comment: [How `trim()` works with your sample.](http://ideone.com/wr6tL7)

Comment: `trim()` works fine for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on using regular expressions<sup>*</sup>, you can do it this way:

```
s = s.replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", "");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/cWTG2g)

The expression removes a sequence of spaces at the beginning (i.e. after an `^` anchor) or at the end (i.e. before the `$` anchor).

<sup>*</sup> Presumably, you may want to do it only as a learning exercise, because `trim()` method does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I accept this answer because sometimes, trim() does not remove the newline. But your regex works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex for this, `trim()` will do the job.

```
String result = oldstring.trim();
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/c8Jxrn)